Why are the new lines getting indented in my Microsoft Word document?
Why are the new lines in the following sentence getting indented in an Office 365 Microsoft Word document, and how can I fix the issue?
Data Shuffling: Distinct clause in a query in a distributed database will not work here since 
      when you combine distinct values from individual nodes that value may be repeated in the 
      final result.


I'm not pressing Enter and am typing one complete sentence
Pressing Backspace to remove the spaces from the left edge of the newlines does not work either


It sounds like auto formatting has been applied either due to the formatting type set or Word applying formatting based on the formatting manually applied in other parts of the document (if applicable)

does it happen if you omit the colon?

This post (referenced above by the SO team) answered my question. Thank you all for trying to help. In my case, I think, some of my issue may be related to what @JW0914 suspected.

There are several indent settings that can be applied to a Word paragraph. To reset the indents, put the insertion point in the paragraph, click the Paragraph Settings symbol in the Home>Paragraph format group.
In the dialog, Indentation area, check the "Special" setting. Change it to (none) and make sure the Left setting is zero, then click OK. That should set the paragraph to have no indent.
If all paragraphs are like that, you can select them and make the change. You should also check the settings for the "Normal" style (or whatever style is assigned to the paragraph) in the Styles panel, and make sure it has no indent settings.

Click on that paragraph, and check its paragraph settings. You might also want to check the paragraph settings for the style that that paragraph is set to. (That would be the better route if you don't want that indentation anywhere in your document.)

This would have been the answer if the full steps had been provided
